# Request Google Search results with Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, search

I want to complement my webservice with a list of results provided by Google Search. My target is to receive the first 10-20 results by specifying some keywords and some other information (data range for example).

What possibilities do I have? Can this even be realised only by using client-side technology like Javascript? Or do I eventually have to rely on a dynamically loaded PHP script which loads and analyses the HTML code by using cURL?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check out their [JSON search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html) (which is a part of their larger [custom search API](http://www.google.com/cse/)). The example on that page is in javascript, but you could just as easily implement that in php.

Comment: @Max: just a note, be careful to use "custom search API" and not "Google Web Search API" which has recently been deprecated and which will stay here for 3 years only now. Googling around chances are that you get some code samples from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it in the past with a cURL request and the Google AJAX API:

```
function getResults($term,$page = 0){
    $googleurl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".(str_replace(' ','+',$term);
    if($page >0){
        $googleurl .= "&start=".($page*10);
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$googleurl);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $Page_Contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $Page_Contents;
}
$keywordCheck = array('ajax','php','cURL','other search terms');

foreach($keywordCheck as $wordKey => $wordValue){
    $term = str_replace(' ','+',$wordValue);
    for($i =0; $i < 5; $i++){
        $page = getResults($term,$i);
        if(preg_match("/mysite.com/",$page)){
            $links = explode('GsearchResultClass',$page);
            foreach ($links as $key => $value){
                if(preg_match("/mysite.com/",$value)){
                    preg_match("/url\":\"([^\"]*)\",/",$value,$match);
                    $match = str_replace('",','',str_replace('url":"','',$match[0]));
                    $results[$wordValue] .= $wordValue. ' is ranked #'.(($i*10)+($key)).': '.$match.'<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sleep(2);
}
```

then in in the page body:

```
<div id="results">
    <?php foreach($results as $key => $value){
        if($value == ''){
            echo '<p>'.$key.' not found in top 50 results</p>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
    }
    }?>
</div>
```

Some points to understand:

1) Use sleep() to pause between queries to avoid getting banned for overburdening the server

2) Last time I checked, the search api limits you to 1000 queries per day, so plan accordingly

3) The API queries a different database than the www.google.com, so results might be slightly different then what you see when you do a normal search

This script just checks the position(s) of my urls on certain keywords I want to monitor the position of within the first 50 results... obviously you would need to make adjustments if you were not focused on 1 site...

to add custom filters, just do an "advanced" search and look at the query string, its the same for the API. Just append as needed, like for a date range of Jan 1 2011 - Jan 24 2011:

```
$googleurl .= '&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F4%2F2011%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F24%2F2011';
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. But is there any way to simulate a user search request by a client-side programming language, therefore making it look like if the user himself made the request and not the server? Or will this effort be prevented by same-origin policy?

Comment: you could use JavaScript to redirect the client to a specially crafted google search result url, but any kind of AJAX type request that would keep them on your site is going to require cURL or some other cross domain request method. Many Google services will reject requests from cURL calls unless you add in a user agent string from a browser... but beware as Google might ban you if they catch on...  what exactly are you trying to do with your client-side google search results?